# Toggle content in absolute/right position

Tags: jquery

When i put a content (position absolute) to right, and when i want to toggle it, the animation send him at the left, the content is no static :/ and i don't want that.

```
<div class="container">

                <div id="myPreNav" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100px;">
                        <div style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 10px; background: #800000; width: 100px;">test</div>
                </div>

                <div id="toggle" style="background: #eeeeaa;">TOGGLE</div>

</div>
```

js:

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('#myPreNav').toggle("slow");
});
```

see problem in action : http://jsfiddle.net/fE2Th/9/

what can i do ?

Comment: Sorry, what do you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/):

```
$('#toggle').click(function () {
    $('#myPreNav').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fE2Th/10/

When you use `toggle` it animates the width of the `#myPreNav` causing the shift of the text content. `slideToggle` will only transition height leaving the text static.